# Calculating the Option price using Quantlib

Tags: quantlib

I can calculate the fair price of a European Option using `Quantlib` as below -

```
import QuantLib as ql 
maturity_date = ql.Date(15, 1, 2016)
spot_price = 127.62
strike_price = 130
volatility = 0.20 
dividend_rate =  0.0163
option_type = ql.Option.Call

risk_free_rate = 0.001
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()

calculation_date = ql.Date(8, 5, 2015)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(option_type, strike_price)
settlement = calculation_date
eu_exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(maturity_date)
european_option = ql.VanillaOption(payoff, eu_exercise)

spot_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(
    ql.SimpleQuote(spot_price)
)
flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
    ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, risk_free_rate, day_count)
)
dividend_yield = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
    ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, dividend_rate, day_count)
)
flat_vol_ts = ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(
    ql.BlackConstantVol(calculation_date, calendar, volatility, day_count)
)
bsm_process = ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess(spot_handle, 
                                           dividend_yield, 
                                           flat_ts, 
                                           flat_vol_ts)
```

This is perfect. However I want to see the **actual calculation engine** to look into the **actual formula** being used for the calculation.

Can you please help me to find the actual file location to see the formula being used? I have searched various files in my local file-system of `~ql` and also online resources like https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/d2/d98/analyticeuropeanengine_8hpp_source.html, but failed to find such.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with it, but based on naming seems likely simply a BSM implementation.  What details are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

QuantLib-Python is actually using [SWIG to run C++ code](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)

I expect it is running compiled C++ code underneath so you won't find the actual lines of code on your computer

But assuming your `ql.VanillaOption` and your `ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess` are connected with a `ql.AnalyticEuropeanEngine` pricing engine, the engine's code is [here](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/pricingengines/vanilla/analyticeuropeanengine.cpp) and you will see that on Line 71 it calls the Black Calculator [here](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/pricingengines/blackcalculator.cpp) which is doing the calculations.

Comment: So if I make a change in https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/pricingengines/vanilla/analyticeuropeanengine.cpp, how that can be implemented in my calculation? I am using Xcode to run the C++ code (also python)

Comment: @Bogaso, You appear to be using python for your scripting in your original question so it is not clear that you're running your scripts using C++ as well. As long as you have complied the QuantLib library from the original C++ source and then used SWIG to generate the Python module, you can: 1/ edit the C++ code in original source; 2/ recompile the C++ library; 3/ regenerate the Python module. In other words if you edit the C++ source files you have to rebuild the library from source to recreate the binaries (which are then translated to a Python module via SWIG).

Comment: My question was that, what should be the bottommost source file, that to be modified. Should I download the QuantLib-1.19.tar.gz from https://bintray.com/quantlib/releases/QuantLib and then untar it and then modify the required file?

Comment: yes, modify and then recompile to obtain the updated binaries (i.e. run ./configure, make, make install etc). After you've done that, if you're going to use Python, download Quantlib-SWIG and then compile that to obtain the modified Quantlib Python module.